# Can anyone recommend a free FTP client for Linux that allows scheduled transfers?

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm looking to do nightly backups - copy files from a dev server to my local machine. I'm on Ubuntu Lucid, and currently use FileZilla for FTP, but it doesn't support scheduled transfers and based on their discussion forums, it never will.

Can anyone recommend a free, GUI ftp client that supports scheduled transfers and runs on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out cron and rsync.

This might be better served at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically asked for a GUI client.

Comment: That's amazing... I just 'brushed off' the GUI part.  My mistake.  Try NcFTP - it's curses but sorta GUIeee